# Area bound (divided) by the y axis and a list data

Tags: list-manipulation

I have an array of points in two dimensional plane, say `A={{x1, y1}, {x2, y2},..., {x2000, y2000}}`. The closed-loop formed by these points (by joining each point with two neighboring points and `{x1, y1}` with `{x2000,y2000}`) always lies on both sides of the Y-axis (x>0 and x<0). Here, I want to calculate the area of the two portions of this closed-loop, which lie on the two sides of the Y-axis. In other words, I want to calculate the areas bound by the Y-axis and the portion of the loop lying on x>0 and x<0 sides respectively.

Not able to figure out any way out, will appreciate any help.

PS: Attached pic shows the original loop and the Discretized area under it, which are not same !!

[image]

Comment: Please provide some code, even if it's just examples of your input and expected output. Ideally please post what you've tried so far. Otherwise we have to do a lot of work to help you out :)

Comment: So if you have points like `pts = CirclePoints[20] + RandomReal[{-.2, .2}, {20, 2}];` for example, do you mean you just want to chop their polygon in half about the vertical Y axis and take the area like:
`Area@RegionIntersection[Polygon@pts, 
  HalfPlane[{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}]]` and `Area@RegionIntersection[Polygon@pts, 
  HalfPlane[{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {-1, 0}]]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is similar to @flinty  but we use `WindingPolygon` since we can deal with self-intersecting contour.

```
pts = CirclePoints[20] + RandomReal[{-.2, .2}, {20, 2}];
reg = WindingPolygon[pts];
reg1 = RegionIntersection[reg, HalfPlane[{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}]];
reg2 = RegionIntersection[reg, HalfPlane[{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {-1, 0}]];
Show[{HighlightMesh[
   DiscretizeRegion[reg1], {Style[2, Orange], Style[1, White]}], 
  HighlightMesh[
   DiscretizeRegion[reg2], {Style[2, Cyan], Style[1, White]}]}, 
 Axes -> True]
{Area[reg], Area[reg1], Area[reg2]}
```

The other way is use `FilledCurve` to construct the region.

```
pts = CirclePoints[20] + RandomReal[{-.2, .2}, {20, 2}];
reg = DiscretizeGraphics[
   Graphics[FilledCurve[{Line /@ Partition[pts, 2, 1, 1]}]]];
reg1 = RegionIntersection[reg, ImplicitRegion[x >= 0, {x, y}]] // 
   DiscretizeRegion;

reg2 = RegionIntersection[reg, ImplicitRegion[x <= 0, {x, y}]] // 
   DiscretizeRegion;
{Area[reg], Area[reg1], Area[reg2]}
Show[HighlightMesh[reg1, {Style[2, Orange], Style[1, White]}], 
 HighlightMesh[reg2, {Style[2, Cyan], Style[1, White]}], 
 Graphics[{Red, Point[pts]}], Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It seems to be working perfect for working examples, but for my real data, the discretized area is not same as bound by the data points. I have attached the image in the original query. Will appreciate any further help. Also area of the two regions is not adding up to total area under the loops.

Comment: @user49535  The discrete points cannot determine the curved domain.